# Tensorflow: how to apply a conditional operation that is differentiable to a Tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to define a Tensorflow operation that allows me to, given a tensor, return a boolean tensor of the same size where all values in the tensor greater than 0 are set to 1, and all other values are set to 0.
I have tried using tf.cond, tf.where, x>0, but I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph 
for ops that do not support gradients, between variables
```

Are there Tensorflow operation(s) that will allow me to perform this binary thresholding that are also differentiable/have defined gradients?

Here is the code that is causing the error:
x1 and x2 are tensors of shape (32, 128, 128, 1):

```
diff = tf.abs(x1-x2)
diff = tf.to_float(diff > 0.0)
y = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(diff, axis=[1, 2, 3]))
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried using that is giving you the error?

Comment: Yes, just added the code that is causing the error.

Comment: What do you want to compute with: `tf.abs`?

Comment: Essentially I want to find the absolute difference in pixel values.

Comment: The answer I provided gives you the absolute difference between the values of two tensors. Let me know if I need to update something.